# Using stored procedure to insert data into table from multiple table

Tags: sql, postgresql

1.I have a table indexes_list(node_id(integer**PK**),indexrelid(oid**PK**),schemaname(name),indexrelid(name) and this is an empty table.

2.I have a table nodes(node_id(integer**PK**),node_name(name),connstr(text),last_snap_id(integer) and i already have a row in the table (1,local,dbname=postgres,0) and this table has a auto generated sequence('nodes_node_id_seq')

3.I have to collect data from pg_stat_user_indexes(indexrelid,schemaname,indexrelname)

Question: I have to create a stored procedure in order to INSERT data into indexes_list from the multiple table nodes and pg_stat_user_indexes?

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not need a function or a stored procedure to copy data from multiple tables into another one.

Example:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (c INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (42);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t2 (c INT);
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (49);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t3 (c INT);
```

Inserting data from `t1` and `t2` into `t3` (all tables have the same number of columns and the data types match):

```
INSERT INTO t3
SELECT c FROM t1
UNION ALL
SELECT c FROM t2;
```

Content of `t3`:

```
SELECT * FROM t3;

 c  
----
 42
 49
(2 Zeilen)
```

Comment: I receive error saying that each UNION query must have the same number of columns and node_id in indexess_list is not allowing me to insert data

Comment: @virsnuparameswaran it is because both `SELECTS` have a different number of columns. Constraint both queries to the columns you need only